# Convert list to comma separate values in django template

Tags: python, django

In a view I can do:

```
l = ['one', 'two', 'three']
', '.join(l)
>>> 'one, two, three'
```

Is there a way to do the same in the template, or do I need to create a custom template filter?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a builtin filter for this. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)

> Filter arguments that contain spaces must be quoted; for example, to
>   join a list with commas and spaces you’d use `{{ list|join:", " }}.`

Answer (score 0):

This would be the template filter:

```
@register.filter
def list_to_comma_separated_string(l):
    try:
        return ', '.join(l)
    except:
        return None
```

Comment: A bare `except` is always a poor idea. And why not return an empty string instead of `None`?

Comment: This is a standard template filter. No need to redo it here.